# Regular Expression Date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have notes column in the Oracle Database & I need to extract the dates from theses .The data in Notes column can contain a string with the Character or Character with Dates .I just need the dates to be populated else blank.

Notes
PO Invoice number 1234
PO invoice number 34555
addnsd;01/01/2016;01/04/2016;ssnfdskjnfkjsnfk
andksnd;01/02/2016;02/01/2016;sdnskjnfk
Hotel
Loding

Thanks
Aditi

Comment: Bad design.  Can you re-factor?  Is date always in MM/DD/YYY format, and separated by ";" ?

Comment: Yes it would be in MM/DD/YYYY but the data can be  -:  asasds;01/01/2016;01/02/2016;sdsdsfdf                                                 or                                  dadad;adsdsd;01/02/2016;02/10/2016;sadsadsdsd

Comment: Is the example you show multiple rows from a table, or one row?

Comment: multiple rows from a table

Answer (score 0):

\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}  this will match those date formats

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Can you show an example on OP data?

Comment: This is much like your solution, except it uses the predefined value for digit `\d` instead of a specific set `[0-9]` like your example.  So '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}' is identical to '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'  You can find a list of these predefined values here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#sthref553

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with notes(text) as (
select 'PO Invoice number 1234' from dual union all
select 'PO invoice number 34555' from dual union all
select 'addnsd;01/01/2016;01/04/2016;ssnfdskjnfkjsnfk' from dual union all
select 'andksnd;01/02/2016;02/01/2016;sdnskjnfk' from dual union all
select 'Hotel' from dual union all
select 'Loding' from dual
)
select text, listagg(date_string, ';') within group ( order by date_string)
from (
        select distinct text, regexp_substr(text, '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', 1, level) as date_string
        from notes
        connect by regexp_instr(text, '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', 1, level) != 0
     )
group by text
```

This uses DISTINCT, so if you have the same date more than once in a row, you will only get 1 occurrence.